# Android listview error: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list' but i have two listviews

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have an app which gets data from a url and then puts it into a listview. I want to do this from two urls so i have two fragments and two xml files in which this happens. But i get the error 
`Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`
I have the id set to list in my xml file, but wont there be a problem when there are two xml files? I cant have the same id right?

My xml files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListFragment">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Framelayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DetailsFragment">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"/>

</Framelayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your `Activity.` May be you extend `ListActivity.`

You have to extend an `Activity` will resolve your issue

**Second solutions is**
define id as below format

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Resolved your issue?

Comment: Thanks, it was the id!

Answer (score 1):

no it won't create any problem as android will solve the duplication at runtime and also listview is outdated and you should start using recyclerview,which is much better than listview.